# Neutral Ground Bonding with 2 Main Breakers

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding, neutral

My electrical service has a meter outside, followed immediately by a 200A breaker, then feeder wires head into my basement and supply a “main” panel with another 200a main breaker. This main panel has the ground and neutral bonded. My question is, should it? How would I know if the ground and neutral are bonded somewhere else outside?

There was a previous “main” panel inside that had no main breaker, just the feeder wires into the lugs, and that old panel did not have a bonded neutral/ground. I bought this house a year and a half ago and it had an electrical fire before I bought so I’m a little paranoid about that whole thing, and just want to make sure it’s good. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S6RF.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Who is your electrical utility?

Answer (score 6):

In your case you can make the main breaker the inside panel.   Label the outside disconnect according to [NEC 230.85(3)](https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=847.0).

> EMERGENCY DISCONNECT, NOT SERVICE EQUIPMENT

Now. Your old panel has a dog's breakfast of random breaker types, and your new panel has the exact same thing but much worse.  This does not work.  The various breakers are not interchangeable - they seem to fit, but they cause  a bus stab burn-up and panel fire.  And didn't you say that's why you replaced this panel?

And that 50A GFCI breaker at bottom left is just a disaster. It's a mismatch (looks like type MP / QP), it's not seated properly, and it looks like it's being pulled to the side.  That's gotta be corrected, as well as all the other non-BR breakers.

Comment: lets make it 300k

Comment: @Traveler hopefully enough to reinstate Monica!